# Linq statement with two where clauses

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, lambda

I'm trying to work out the following.

```
    public class Competition
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<ResultInfo> ResultInfos { get; set; }
    public IList<Event> ChildEvents { get; set; }
}


public class ResultInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string ResultInfoName { get; set;}
    public int Season { get; set; }
}

public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    public IList<ResultInfo> ResultInfos { get; set; } 
}
```

I'm trying the query as below to try to get season "2013" of result info from competitions and events. If anyone knows, plesae advise .

```
if (year.HasValue)
{
   model = model.Where(x => x. ??           
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
var competitions = new Competition(); // Populated competition class

var results = (from c in competitions
               from e in c.ChildEvents
               from ri in e.ResultInfos
               where ri.Season == 2013).ToList();
```

It's unclear why you need an additional `where` but you could extend it and have another clause such as

```
where ri.Season == 2013 && EventName == "Event"
```

As @von.v has pointed out, you can access `ResultInfos` directly via the Competition class, so you can simplify it via:

```
   var results = (from c in competitions
                  from ri in c.ResultInfos
                  where ri.Season == 2013).ToList();
```

Comment: You would then need to concatenate on the results from the ResultInfos stored directly in the Competition object. (competition.ResultInfos.Where(ri => ri.Season == 2013));

Comment: how about the `ResultInfo`s in `Competition`?

Comment: One more thing, how about suggesting to do a union of both, the `ResultInfo`s in `Competition` and those that are in `Event`s. I think he may need that, although I wasn't sure what exactly is his question. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't undersant what do you want ? If you want the competition which have events with results infos in 2013 and result infos also in 2013 you can do this :

```
model.Where(c => c.ChildEvents
                  .SelectMany(ce => ce.ResultInfos)
                  .Where(ri => ri.Season == 2013).Count() > 0
            &&
            c.ResultInfos.Where(ri => ri.Season == 2013).Count() > 0)
     .ToList();
```

But I'm not sure that I undersand what you need